# Is there any way to reload kong using REST api postman

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

if anybody know How to do kong reload (api gateway) using postman api. please post the curl command for the same.

execute kong reload inside container. but it is time consuming.

Comment: Why do you need to do a reload? Conf changed should be handle without reload

Comment: sometimes cache didn't get updated. it took time so kong reload help us to get it refresh immediately.